# Что не так с классом?

Tags: php

Создал класс. В нем функция, которая выполняет некоторые действия, после их выполнения хочу передать ответ публичной переменной, но не получается.
Не могу понять почему.

```
class Content extends DB_Connect {

   public $keywords;
   public $description;
   public $title;

   function Pages () {
        $view_get = empty($_GET['page']) ? 'main' : $_GET['page'];
        $sql_query = mysql_query("select title, keywords, description, content from pages where seo_name = '$view_get'");

        if (!$sql_query) {
            echo "Страницы, которую Вы ищите не существует или Вы ошиблись при наборе адреса.";
        } elseif ($view_get == "order_page") {
            $this->keywords = "Заказать визитку, Содание заказа, Оформление заказа";
            $this->description = "Оформление заказа на печать";
            $this->title = "Оформление заказа";
            require_once 'temp/order_page.php'; 
        } elseif (isset($_GET['admin'])) {
            require_once'admin.php';
            $this->title = "Администраторская панель";
            $AdminEditContent = new AdminEditContent;
            $AdminEditContent->AdminPages();
        } else {
            $main = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query);
            echo $main['content'];
            $this->keywords = $main['keywords'];
            $this->description = $main['description'];
            $this->title = $main['title'];
        }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Конкретней.

Comment: не получается передать в классе результат из функции Pages() в переменную public $title; (например)

Comment: @kiberchainik, когда вы вызываете функцию публичным переменным присваиваются соотв. значения , смотрите ответ там все верно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Content extends DB_Connect {
      function Pages () {
       ...
       return $result;
      }
}
```

... в основном теле программы

```
$result = Content::Pages();
```

или так

```
    class Content extends DB_Connect {
          public $result;

          function Pages () {
           ...
           $this->result = $result;
          }
    }
```

... в основном теле программы

```
$content = new Content;
$content->Pages();
$result = $content->result;
```

или я тоже что-то не понял?